# How to remove ending from sample names

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to remove endings from sample names in my data frame. There are about 200 samples so I was hoping there was a way to end the name before the first - (common to each sample).

Examples of names are:

```
Glyc.1.20C.1wk-ATGGTTCACCCG-CATCAGTACGCC-R1.fastq
Glyc.1.20C.2m-CACTACGCTAGA-GTTCCTCCATTA-R1.fastq  
Glyc.1.20C.2wk-GCTCGAAGATTC-CGAGGGAAAGTC-R1.fastq 
Glyc.1.20C.3m-GTAGGTGCTTAC-GCATAAACGACT-R1.fastq
```

Using the change `colnames(x) <- c("Glyc.1.20C.1wk, etc)` would take me forever.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-split-strings-in-r/

Answer (score 2):

If `df` is your dataframe, take the names, remove everything after the first `-`, and reset the names to the new short values...

```
names(df) <- gsub("\\-.+","",names(df))
```